# Should we burninate the [priority] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

This tag is a useless meta tag. It has no tag wiki summary and it is highly implausible that somebody can be an expert in [priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/priority). Some examples of how this tag was used:

- [priority in macro (++x vs x++ in macro)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28266955/3920237) OP meant order of evaluation
- [GSA - Determining which queries need higher Click Rank from ASR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28226857/3920237) Although "Priority" is used in a semi-programming context here, the master tag [google-search-appliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-search-appliance) is enough to convey context
- [Find Kth smallest of array using segment tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185244/find-kth-smallest-of-array-using-segment-tree) This question is off-topic and badly formed, the tag does nothing to help
- [Priority results elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084856/priority-results-elasticsearch) "Priority" isn't used in a programming context here
- [CSS priority issues in iPad's proprietary browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902188/css-priority-issues-in-ipads-proprietary-browser) OP means CSS specificity

As you can see, people are using the tag to mean completely different things and the tag contributes nothing to the posts. Burn it.

Comment: Some should be retagged to [priority-queue] or [thread-priority].

Comment: I dunno; is this really a... No, sorry; even I can't finish this bad pun!

Comment: Yes, this really is a priority :-P (I can)

Comment: Title idea: [priority] burnination

Comment: Is funny that the user that wanted this is now deleted... actually is sad, such a fine gentleman isn't around anymore :(.

Comment: Excellent use of "burninate," which is a perfectly cromulent word.

Comment: How/why did this question get the featured tag?

Comment: @Laurel that is explained in the notice at the start of the post that links to [this process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md), step 2 we're in. One of our RO's flagged the post for moderator attention requesting the retag.

Comment: @Laurel keep in mind that we are in a test phase of this process. When we finalize that the control over tags and the process will probably be handed back to the CM/Mod team. The SOCVR will be back to faciliting then.

Comment: Title should be something like: "Should be a [priority] for us to remove such tag?

Answer (score 34):

I do not believe this is a meta tag. The [priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/priority) tag attempts to indicate the user is asking about prioritization of a job or process or some internal priority ranking. Were it to be a meta tag, it would mean the question ITSELF WAS a priority and obviously that should be removed. I do not believe OP truly understood what a meta tag meant.

Further, just because "no one can be an expert in it" doesn't mean it's not a useful tag. I believe the same could be said for [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) but because those questions are about lists, it is useful to tag it. There is a reason being an expert is not one of the four criteria.

I do have concerns about how the tag should be used. I see [firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase) questions regarding OrderByPriority, as well as questions about task priority, and some others as well. The OrderByPriority should be retagged with a [order-by-priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-by-priority) or [orderbypriority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orderbypriority) whichever is grammatically correct. Similar situations should be retagged apprpriately.

Then we should decide if [priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/priority) should mean 1) [thread-priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread-priority), 2) [task-priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/task-priority) (which currently doesn't exist yet, and perhaps should be called or synonymed with [process-priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/process-priority)) or 3) [priority-queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/priority-queue). Note that technically, [thread-priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread-priority) is intra-process while [task-priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/task-priority) would be inter-process. If there is something that makes this tag burninatable, it would be the confusion around which of those three tags it maps to. We should also consider if [scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheduling) or other sched* tags would be useful to help with some retags.

I posted this originally attempting to defend the tag, at the very least with a stay of execution. However, after I made my arguments, I convinced myself that **the confusion around the above three tags is enough to support it being blacklisted**. (That was difficult to write, in case you're wondering. Science, 1; pride, 0.) I believe the trifecta will receive the bulk of the retags, with a couple getting sent to more library specific tags or simply having references to priority removed.

Comment: +1 for humility and sound reasoning.

Comment: that's the problem - it's too vague/ambiguous to categorize a question

Comment: btw I first downvoted the answer, thinkning it defends the tag with weak argumentation (and wondering how someone could call it "sound"); after seeing the finish, I upvoted it instead, having found out it unlimately doesn't (entertainment: 1, clarity: 0).

Comment: When I first approached it, I was against the proposal because of the reasons stated by OP. The more I thought about it, the more I realized OP was right, but for the wrong reasons. I think it's important to make sure that right action happens for the right reason.

Comment: AFAIK, the tags are not to classify questions out of some idealistic reason, but to aid in searches of questions relevant to one's needs, and to facilitate defining domains of human specialization. Can you be an expert in [c++]? Sure. In [priority]? Nopenopenope. Will a user who searches for related questions get them when she uses the tag? No way: priority is way too big of a concept. [list] is a data structure, so one can reasonably claim to be an expert in data structures and can look for such questions, iff they pertain to the CS aspect of it, not merely using one in passing...

Comment: So, even though one uses lists in one's code, it's not a good enough reason to use the [list] tag unless the question is list-specific. Questions about implementations of lists, or algorithms that work on lists? Sure. Similar reasoning applies to [priority], except that while a [list] is a data structure, [priority] is not really a single well-defined CS/CSE concept. It can refer to priority in a queue, or thread priority, or, or, or... So, not useful. We're not an encyclopedia nor Twitter nor Tumbler. Tags on SO are used very differently than on Twitter. That's what I make of it.

Comment: @Kuba I'm not really sure I follow what you're saying. Yes, tags are used for making meaningful searches. I wish I could red-green highlight your comments so I could ask for a follow up, but I'm pretty sure we agree on most of it? Not sure though, it was really hard to follow. Pretty sure tags here are used exactly as they are on Tumblr, though. They're just meta-data to aid in searching. We're just a little more strict in curating those tags than your typical 16-year-old microblogger, I guess.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks everyone, for giving this priority! This tag has been...

[image: puff the magic dragon]

All [priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/priority) questions have been reviewed and either edited or closed and deleted.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped burninate the tag!

Answer (score -11):

Bizarre. Apparently priority queues come up too rarely for the tag to be useful. Maybe we can do a lesser thing and edit the tag to say if this isn't task scheduling you have the wrong tag.

Incidentally, the second newest question uses the tag correctly. [Assigning priority to the tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575408/assigning-priority-to-the-tasks)

Comment: You can either suggest to have a better tag for such questions or propose the improved tag-wiki?

Comment: There's currently no usage guidance for this very ambiguous tag.  Is task priority truly the best meaning for the tag?

Comment: @ryanyuyu; All other potential meanings are off topic or have a more specific tag (priority queue is too specific). Check the tag wiki edit queue for my pending edit pointing the other use cases to their relevant tags.

Comment: The CloudSim question is a question where a program has to solve a priority problem. Most of these will be scheduling problems.