# Do tags come back to life after burnination?

Tags: discussion, tags

What happens after a tag has been burninated?
Will users be disallowed to create it afterwards?

Comment: Only with some religions/faiths.  If you worship PHP, there is no afterlife for you, or your tags.  The tags are destined for purgatory forever, you will be promoted to middle-management with special responsibility for customer satisfaction.

Comment: *[sigh]* ... Nowadays it seems that every comment that is off-color in the slightest gets flagged.  We [really do hate fun here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), don't we?

Comment: @RobertHarvey If I upvote your comment, does that mean I really hate fun too. Best not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most tags do not come back, but some need to be put on the list to be blocked, which is the way to prevent a tag from being created ever again. Leaving out that step normally isn't much of a problem and allows creation of the same tag in maybe a new context.

For some tags that were burninated some [regulars](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/30621265#30621265) of the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room run a check to see if new questions appear in those tags. When found they are swiftly dealt with.

On burninate requests that follow the new [process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323121/evaluation-of-socvrs-burnination-process) the post notice *Completed Burninate Request* is added by a moderator when the [burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285084/578411) is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed):

> This tag has been **burninated!** If you notice it re-appearing with some frequency, please [propose that the tag gets blocked.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239189/239192#239192)

Comment: Thanks @Nathan for understanding what I really meant to say.