# We need to relook at what our [priority] is

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Two and a half years ago, we managed to burninate [priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/priority), [Should we burninate the [priority] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285084/should-we-burninate-the-priority-tag). [priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/priority) was the 5th tag, in the first set of 5 tags which were burned using the then new [formalized burnination procedure.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323121/evaluation-of-socvrs-burnination-process)

Come 2018, [the tag has reappeared, with 115 questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/priority) The issues with the tag still remain, and corsiKa's [Spring 2016 argument to get rid of the tag, still holds good.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321735/4099593)

Now going through the 4 reasons for burnination:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   No. Just the tag [priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/priority) does not describe what the contents of the question are, as we don't know what priority the poster is asking about. The disambiguity of the tag is more detailed in [the linked answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321735/4099593):

   > I see [firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase) questions regarding OrderByPriority, as well as questions about task priority, and some others as well. The OrderByPriority should be retagged with a [order-by-priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/order-by-priority) or [orderbypriority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/orderbypriority) whichever is grammatically correct. Similar situations should be retagged apprpriately.
   >
   > Then we should decide if [priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/priority) should mean 1) [thread-priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread-priority), 2) [task-priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/task-priority) (which currently doesn't exist yet, and perhaps should be called or synonymed with [process-priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/process-priority)) or 3) [priority-queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/priority-queue). Note that technically, [thread-priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread-priority) is intra-process while [task-priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/task-priority) would be inter-process. If there is something that makes this tag burninatable, it would be the confusion around which of those three tags it maps to. We should also consider if [scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheduling) or other sched* tags would be useful to help with some retags.

   It is not unambiguous, as the tag can mean either thread priority, or a process priority, or a priority inversion. 
   Additionally, [10 posts have been tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/priority+priority-web-sdk) with the [priority-web-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/priority-web-sdk) tag, which can be retagged almost immediately, as the tag is redundant.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Partial No. The priority tag  itself is being used for on-topic posts, however it needs another tag to remain on-topic for the site and to describe the question clearly. Therefore I am adding a partial No to this question
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   No. The tag by itself, does not add any new information to the post, other than what has already been present. If tagged with [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread), [sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdk), or another tag, then it would add more information. It can't be classified as a meta-tag though,
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   No. Priority has 2 meanings in common contexts, which are  1. The original meaning which is "the right to take precedence", under which tags like [priority-queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/priority-queue), [thread-priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thread-priority), etc fall under. 2. Web SDK named Priority

As all the 4 answers are No, the tag certainly is worth another burnination.

Comment: Umm… it hasn't been "just months" after the burnination, it's been 2 1/2 years.

Comment: @StephenLeppik It was re-created on 2016-11-08 10:29:56, and it was burninated on 2016-05-10 03:00:00. So a span of 6 months.

Comment: Found out [about it recently](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/43848218#43848218), after [we created a bot](https://github.com/SOBotics/Revenant) to monitor the [recreation of burned tags](https://github.com/SOBotics/Nursery/issues/9).

Comment: It looks like a gap has been identified in the Stack Overflow processes. There are no controls in place to stop the recreation of a tag identified as unwanted. May I suggest the Stack Exchange team should fix the root cause of the problem while the community is busy performing another cleanup. And to state the obvious, a bot monitoring for the activity allows the transgression to occur. It is *reactive* and requires extra work. The goal should be a *proactive* fix so the problem does not occur in the first place.

Comment: @jww, there are controls in place. Once burned, a tag can only be recreated by a user with 1.5k rep. The issue is that we assume a 1.5k user to be sane enough not to recreate burned tags.

Comment: @BhargavRao - Ah, my bad. It looks like it missed the mark then. Stack Exchange is now in the feedback part of the development lifecycle. The control needs to be further tuned because the world is full of smarter mice.

Comment: @BhargavRao "Once burned, a tag can only be recreated by a user with 1.5k rep" I find this misleading. It implies that creating and recreating a tag has different requirements. To my knowledge, there is no such distinction.

Comment: @JETM, I think there is. Check this answer by animuson, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372143/4099593. (I came to know about that restriction after that answer).

Comment: [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) says tag creation is awarded at 1500. (And either I'm not allowed to create tags myself, or I'm too dumb to figure out how.)

Comment: Ah, Interesting. @JETM, I will ask someone internally and let you know when I get an answer.

Comment: @BhargavRao Seems like that answer is saying that the bar is higher *as opposed to using a tag that currently exists*, though I might be reading it wrong.

Comment: Oops, then jww was correct, @JohnMontgomery, and we don't have controls in place. Thanks for explaining that.

Comment: @jww, follow up on that. Looks like we don't have a system in place to prevent recreation of tags. Sorry about that, I misinterpreted another answer. My apologies, and it's totally my mistake.

Comment: I was hoping this was a tongue-in-cheek attempt to start a discussion about SO's evolving priorities. Alas...

Comment: I would say: keep the tag. It saves some users a lot of typing `"Can you answer quick, I need this now"`. They can just add the [priority] tag :-)

Comment: @Michel The same argument can be used for any tags with the "DO NOT USE" note. For example [tag:puzzle].

Comment: @Michel Maybe we could make the tag a micro purchase.

Comment: @Michel, we've got the [tag:urgent] for that.

Comment: @BhargavRao _"we assume a 1.5k user to be sane enough not to recreate burned tags"_ Assuming that every user above 1.5k is aware of every tag ever burned seems a bit optimistic. I'm almost 3k and I barely even visit Meta, much less know what tags are burned / renamed / whatever.

Comment: @LuisG., That's a good point, we ideally should be considering a user's meta activity while giving them the privileges to do meta-site activity (like tag creation), and not the main site activity.

Comment: @LuisG. I doubt anyone knows all of the [several hundred](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request+status-completed) tags that were ever burninated by heart.  The idea is that, with 1.5k, you can judge whether the tag creation makes sense on its own, regardless of whether it had been burninated before.

Comment: @BhargavRao That would be a sad change for Meta lurkers like myself (elections aside, I almost never post).

Comment: (Just in case any of you wanna memorize the list of tags, [these are the 355 tags burninated on just MSO](https://github.com/SOBotics/Tagdor/blob/master/StatusCompletedBurninateRequests.csv) and not including those from before the MSO-MSE split)

Comment: @BaummitAugen oops, now we need to find a way to quantify lurking and convert that into meta activity.

Comment: It should be a [priority] for Trogdor.