# Do nicely formatted questions receive more or better answers?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, formatting

I usually try to make sure my questions and answers are nicely written and well formatted (to the best of my ability anyway).

This certainly includes marking code as `code`, especially for individual keywords where they appear because I think this helps set context & readability, and other formatting devices where clarity or emphasis seems useful.

*But sometimes things can have unintended consequences.* It seems possible that such an editing style could discourage people from reading, commenting, or answering.

(Such as: by seeming too formal. Or conferring a sense of intimidating professionalism?)

I don't have any evidence for this - but I wonder if SO or SE has done any [number crunching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376259/data-science-time-november-2018-and-correlations?cb=1) on this topic?

If there were any correlations one way or the other that could be very valuable to us users, and could also be used to improve the editing tools.

Comment: I would think it’s always a combination of readability, interestingness, and difficulty. There’s a sweet spot somewhere right in the middle, but having a super readable question which is off in both other axes doesn’t do any good.

Comment: Not really,.  Nothing wrong with sounding formal or professional and we're not that easily intimidated :)  It is only really a concern the other way around, a poorly formatted question better be interesting quickly or nobody is going to expend the effort to read and fix it.  Your last question was certainly good enough.

Comment: Would be very difficult to perform any kind of "number crunching", since detecting "nicely formatted" posts is not trivial. How would you differentiate programmatically a nicely formatted post from one that isn't?

Comment: @yivi on podcasts and in other places SE staff have talked about this kind of thing for years. I'm not sure what specific mechanisms they use though.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, any question that is written in a good way will surely get more people to read it and to try and answer it. Example, it is always better to show a snippet of the code where the problem occurred instead of taking a screenshot and pasting it here (which could lead to closing the question).

It is fine if you are formal, though no need to write "Dear SO Users" or "thank you", just follow the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and you will be fine :)