# Data science time! December 2018 and answer voting

Tags: discussion, community-moderation, data

Last month we [kicked off our monthly series](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376259/data-science-time-november-2018-and-correlations) of regular, bite-size, data-focused updates for Meta. Thanks to all who contributed to the discussion and suggested ideas for upcoming analyses.

One topic many people were particularly interested in hearing about is recent change to improve how welcoming Stack Overflow is; let's take this month to look at this issue a bit. Internal teams at Stack Overflow have been working on [many projects](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305560/2018-monthly-product-team-updates) related to how developers engage here but let's focus on two events:

- [Jay's blog post at the end of April](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)
- The new [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct), which [launched in August](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/08/07/get-to-know-our-new-code-of-conduct/)

Notice that the blog post is a statement of values that did not involve any product changes, while the CoC launch (while also a statement of values) did involve product changes. When the CoC launched, we [updated options for comment flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313754/updated-comment-flagging-supporting-the-new-code-of-conduct), including adjusting flagging reasons and allowing all users to flag comments on their own post.

What kind of impact can we measure from either of these events? First off, let's walk through a (non-exhaustive) list of quantities that don't exhibit any change over the past year, through both of these events.

- The proportion of questions that are of [good quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302970/how-is-question-quality-measured-in-a-b-tests), and the proportion of questions by new users (`Rep < 111`) that are of good quality
- The proportion of questions that are closed
- The number of comments ever posted per question
- Voting patterns on questions (proportion of questions with positive or negative votes)

We do see changes in flagging patterns since August, but that is expected since more people can flag in more ways since the launch of CoC.

WOW, not so interesting, right?! This is all largely good news for us, though. These changes/events were not disruptive to how Stack Overflow functions overall.

Voting patterns on **answers** are slightly different. First, let's take a look at the trend for answers that have a positive score.

[image]

This plot shows, since the beginning of 2018, what proportion of answers have a positive score at 7 days after posting, and at 60 days after posting. The trend is overall mostly flat, indicating no significant change over the year (this is what the plots of the other quantities I mentioned above look like as well). See how the line for 60 days is shifted higher, indicating that more helpful answers are discovered by 60 days than are found by 7 days.

Next, let's take a look at answers that have a negative score.

[image]

There are several differences for the answers that have a negative score, compared to the positive ones. There *isn't* much difference between 7 days and 60 days after posting, indicating that new unhelpful answers aren't being "discovered" or identified the way new helpful answers are. Also, the overall proportion is much lower; more questions are identified as helpful through a positive score than unhelpful through a negative score by about 4 or 5 times.

Why I chose to include this analysis is that we can see some evidence of change with time here. The proportion of answers with a negative score appears lower *after* Jay's blog post than *before*. How much lower? Using a [t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test), about 1% lower, dropping from about 9% to about 8% (p<<0.05).

The p-value says this is unlikely to be a random effect, but let's think about this a little more. I did just tell you that I looked at a lot of different metrics on Stack Overflow, which means we should worry about [multiple comparisons](https://xkcd.com/882/). On the other hand, this small shift is robust to subsampling approaches. I think it's likely to be real.

So what does a small shift in answer downvoting like this mean? Is it good news or bad news? I am quite confident that opinions will differ, but paired with the lack of change in answer upvoting, question voting, question quality, question closure, etc. I mostly find it interesting that we can probably measure a change in site behavior from a public statement of values alone. These types of metrics are only a few of the ways we are working to understand and quantify the impact of decisions, and we can share more, if there's interest.

That's this month's slightly-more-than-bite-size data science time! Thoughts? Do you have topic ideas for future data science explorations?

Comment: re: downvoted posts: How many "first downvotes" were accompanied by a comment? That seems like a more useful datapoint indicating "welcomingness" than the score alone.

Comment: Can we assume this data includes deleted answers / answers to deleted questions?

Comment: @Shog9 Yep, this includes deleted answers, and what I said about comments includes deleted comments, and so forth.

Comment: About the second graph, isn't it a bit strange that the yellow line is (mostly) above the blue line? Does this mean that some answers have initially a negative score, and as time passes they become positive? It is like the tag followers dislike some answers, but then the googlers that find the answers find them helpful and their score balances out...

Comment: I would call that a 10% decrease in negatively scored answers

Comment: I'd be curious how often over a much longer time period the proportion of answers with a negative score has shifted by a comparable amount without any obvious reason or trigger.

Comment: In the plot analyzing answers, could you mark the two events you highlight at the next plot? Could you share the exact p-value and the odds-ratio? Also how did you make it: comparing the mean before and the mean after the event?  It seems like the number of answers  with a score different from zero is decreasing. What are the absolute values ?

Comment: It's also unlikely to be a random effect since https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics shows a 20% decrease in downvotes at the end of april, which is consistent with fewer negative scores. I'm just surprised answers are affected more than questions.

Comment: @sth I would say that this graphs analyzing voting trends should be on answers and questions, instead of just answers. Parteto says that 20% of the users cast 80% of the votes. A single critic user quitting may explain differences.

Comment: Heh, I wonder how many SO users thought the [welcoming] campaign was about questions.  The only really obvious affect it had was on the number of downvotes, dropped by ~16%.  Answers might be slightly affected by that drop, most DVs are applied to questions.  At arm's length, the total question volume dropped a bit faster than normal, making the average number of answers/question increase.  Until November, the end-of-semester assignments are always rough.

Comment: @user000001 Answers sometimes improve over time, but rarely get worse over time. I assume that this is what happens: someone posts an answer worthy of downvotes. It gets downvoted. It gets edited to be worthy of upvotes. The original downvoter(s) don't retract their votes. Over time, people find the (now helpful) answer through google, and upvote it. At some point between 7 and 60 days, this is enough to turn it from `< 0` to `>= 0`.

Comment: Is the 'positive score' meaning `> 0` or `>= 0`?  Presumably `> 0` (otherwise you've got a summation problem), and by inference it means a smidgeon over 50% of answers have zero score (after 7 and 60 days).  So half of answers get no net score at all.  I wonder how many have no score and how many have equal numbers of up-votes and down-votes (so no net score in terms of votes, but a net benefit to the poster's rep because you get more points for an up-vote than a down-vote).

Comment: Can you post the same graph for previous years? The "isn't very welcoming" thing coincides well with end-of-semester for college - possible confounding variable.

Comment: To me it looks like the percentage of positive answers also has dropped by about 1% with significance. Does it mean the number of neutral answers was increased by 2% in the mean time? Then it may just be lower overall voting activity. One maybe could check if the mean number of votes per answer decreased.

Comment: "This is all largely good news for us, though. These changes/events were not disruptive to how Stack Overflow functions overall." My initial reaction was a bit different. I would have expected an effect (any effect), otherwise why do it at all. I still hope there was a positive effect.

Comment: @Trilarion The intended effect was to make SO look more welcoming, which isn't one of the quantities measured, and will probably be measured by absence of anti-SO trolling on Twitter. SO contributors were afraid (and still are) that a side-effect of the CoC would be an increase in low-quality content, especially by new users. The fact we haven't been inundated with negatively-voted or closed questions tells us those fears haven't materialised. It's possible that there are more bad questions **and** people are discouraged from downvoting them, and these two effects cancel out exactly...

Comment: Your definition of "good question" is still fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yep, positive score means `> 0`, as you presumed there. Most answers have zero or one votes, so the number of answers with a zero score because of equal votes is a minority. I bet those would be interesting answers, though -- polarizing!

Comment: @DanHulme or it means less people care about categorizing questions properly now so we're flooded with more low quality then ever before and the people who care enough to downvote it have reduced. I'm not sure how this dataset makes a statement about either.

Comment: I'm a bit concerned about over-interpreting the stats, thought-provoking as it is. The scatter on the binned points is larger than the alleged shift before/after the post. You could control for e.g. the previous year. This was the first I had even heard of the blog post - did it get many hits? Are the data themselves out there?

Comment: @jtlz2 The blog post resulted in more meta posts than I can count and seemingly endless pages of meta debate (not to mention various high profile users leaving or threatening to). I'm not sure I could have missed it if I was trying to...

Comment: "Using a t-test, about 1% lower, dropping from about 9% to about 8% (p<<0.05)". This seems to imply that you are very confident that there was a 1% drop, but I'm pretty sure that's not what you've tested.

Comment: I agree with "WOW, not so interesting". I am sure much more interesting things can be found in the data, even though they may not be related to the CoC hype. Maybe you shouldn't strive for revelations on a specific topic? Instead, just play with the data as long as you want, and report the most interesting thing you found?

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm not sure about the term "pity-upvotes". I will sometimes give a question an upvote, not because it's a particularly good question, but because I think that it was quite wrong of someone to give it a downvote (especially if it was downvoted with no stated reason). That's not out of pity, it's to set the record straight.

Comment: @mbrig Wary of anecdotal evidence - are the data available?

Comment: Are the queries used for this available? For example, I am interested in what you used for `The proportion of questions that are close` please. It would be helpful, where possible, to share links to the queries generating these stats so others can run them/fork them.

Answer (score 84):

What makes you think that post quality has any relation to the CoC changes in the first place? Voting should hopefully reflect post quality and nothing else. While the CoC changes were almost exclusively about the content of comments, once a question has already been posted.

Voting patterns change over time regardless of blogs and CoC. It is well-known among veteran users that SO has a dip in quality whenever schools start or have exams. It seems to me that the negative score graph is mostly a graph over when most schools have vacation. Turns out that's in the summer. A comparison against previous years is obviously needed.

---

Overall, I would like to see more use of [the scientific method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method). Establish a hypothesis, explain why it is a sound one to begin with, then describe why the methods to verify it make sense. Question your own hypothesis and results, apply critical thinking.

It gets tiresome when SO keeps publishing what's actually just loose theories as "science". Some of the past articles like for example the "every programming technology older than a few year is in decline" were very poor, because it looked at percentage of total rather than amount of questions asked. Yet people don't question them but keep spreading them over the internet as facts.

If you call yourself scientist and these publications science, then prepare to be judged by the quality standards you have set yourself.

What is for example the rationale for using a scale with 1.5 months per square in a graph? What does 7/60 days after posting relate to in the graph - does it show the score of the post 7 days after it was posted? As in, what we see for July 1st actually happened June 23th and May 1st? Or is it showing score of what the post posted at July 1st would get in the future? It would seem that the second version is true? A bit confusing. At any rate, I'm having a hard time applying 7/60 days units to the 1.5 month scale, to for example determine if the post time was made 60 days before school exams.

Comment: Instead of comparing it against previous years, I'd like to see it in the context of month-to-month variation against perhaps a whole year. Is there a spike in variation in the amount of downvoted answers, or is this within normal month-to-month variation? Because there certainly is month-to-month variation, and using a T-test with the sample size Stack Overflow provides, it will nearly always be a significant difference.

Comment: This hits the nail on the head. One of the first things I learned about statistics is that correlation does not imply causality. This question boils down to "here is a correlation, any speculations on the causality?"

Comment: Take for example the article where every programming technology older than a few years was described to be in rapid decline, while all new ones were becoming increasingly popular. They came up to this conclusion by looking at the percentage of questions asked on SO, as a metric for popularity. While the truth was that more questions were asked about pretty much _all_ technologies, old ones and new both gaining in popularity. With the difference that the newer ones took up a percentage once invented, at the cost of already invented ones. The study wasn't scientific but harmful.

Comment: I obviously disagree with your assessment of our work, but I want to clarify what you brought up about what the lines in the graph are communicating. This is marked on the graph, but just to reiterate, the x-axis of each graph shows the date answers were posted, and the lines show the proportion of those answers that have a positive/negative score 7 days after posting or 60 days after posting.

Comment: @Comintern it's ["Correlation does not imply causation"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation). Causality is the principle that every effect has a cause, and every cause has an effect. Causation is the relationship between the cause and the effect.

Comment: I doubt we will come to a consensus here on what exactly the discipline of "Data Science" is, but I think it is safe to say, it is not used in this posting.  All I see are two queries run and then ruminated on.  A Data Scientist this does not make - just an curious Analyst.

Answer (score 24):

The fitted line in the graph over 2018 in the OP doesn't match at all the fitted line in the same data over a 4-year period shown in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377874/7328782). Which one should be believe?

To find out, I did some high-tech data fitting, and come to totally different conclusions:

[image: Julia's plot with manual annotations]

Something big happened October 2016 through March 2017 that caused a change in voting patterns! And what happened at New Year's Eve last year???

---

The comment above is obviously tongue-in-cheek, but serves to point out that trends in time data depend very much on interpretation and on the choice of start and stop points. Unless there is a hypothesis to test, such trend lines can be highly misleading. For example you can [prove there is no global warming](https://wattsupwiththat.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/clip_image002_thumb.jpg) by picking just the right start and stop dates.

Comment: [Global warning is in fact caused by the lack of pirates](https://churchoftheflyingspaghettimonsteraustralia.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/pchart1.jpg).

Comment: @Lundin: That's what the Flying Spaghetti Monster told me personally. There is also [these](http://tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations).

Answer (score 12):

"One topic many people were particularly interested in hearing about is recent change to improve how welcoming Stack Overflow is"

Not very much for screenreader users.

[image: Meta Stack Overflow Not Using Alt Attributes]

Answer (score 10):

The post listed a series of proportions that were not affected by these changes. These are of course important metrics, but I think they tell only part of the story. The other part would be to look at actual numbers indicating the volume of activity (e.g., number of questions, number of answers, number of new registered users, etc.), compared to the general growth trend.

Presumably, an increase in this growth (above the current trend) would indicate that users are encouraged to be more involved, and a decrease would indicate that the existing userbase found this change unwelcome and dialed back on their activity.

Were such numbers looked at?

Comment: Those are also interesting numbers to see; maybe a good idea for a future one of these posts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for your comments and discussion. One great point brought up in a couple of ways was how much these proportions vary over longer periods of time, and how surprising a shift like this is.

[image]

You can see here that there was a long-term trend toward higher values of this proportion of answers with a negative score, and it appears there may have been an inflection point this year. Week-to-week variation is also high.

Like I said in my original post, we can't be sure these kinds of changes are not random but they are some of the important metrics of our community for us to understand and notice in the context of decisions we make.

Comment: Of course you can't trust your eyes much for statistical inference, but doesn't the inflection point precede The Blog Post?

Comment: That looks likely to me too. To be clear, we can't use observational data like this to understand causality like with an A/B test. We want to see if there are changes in important metrics in our community as we make changes and communicate values and so forth.

Comment: The trend line in this graph does something completely different to the one fitted over only 2018 in OP. How do you want us to trust such results? Also, compared to previous years, 2018 is actually pretty flat.

Comment: While you state "we can't use data like this to understand causality" you go on to see "we want to see if there are changes in important metrics ... as we make changes". Why else would you do that if you weren't using this data to understand causality?

Comment: the unkindness in these threads is ironic.

Comment: So you're not sure this isn't random, but using it for decisions nonetheless?

Comment: @worc: Pointing out errors and logical fallacies is not unkind. I’d say it’s the kindest thing you can do, as it allows others to learn from their mistakes and grow. The unkind thing to do is to let people keep their wrong ideas in their heads. :)

Comment: it's awfully close to "just asking questions" and the condescending tone is pretty obvious. that's the irony. not that there aren't mistakes or flaws to point out.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I suspect the effect Julia is reporting is random rather than caused by the blog post or CoC. But many of the comments here either imply or outright say that she is bad at her job. The truth is she is an excellent data scientist and offered to publish these posts because she thought meta would be interested in reading bite-sized data analysis. I hope she continues writing them, but I wouldn't blame her if it's not worth the hassle. :-(

Comment: @JonEricson, Julia — I hope I didn’t imply that Julia is bad at her job, sorry if I came across that way. I have read some pretty insightful posts by Julia. This post just feels too rushed. A blog post (can I call this that?) should not merit the same effort and attention to detail that a scientific paper requires, yet it is being examined here with the same expectations. :/

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I wasn't thinking of you specifically. It sounds like maybe part of the issue is expectation setting?