# Close a question when it gets 3 (or 4) leading 'Close' votes?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close

Five 'Close' votes* from regular users are needed to close a question (or put it 'on hold') ([reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question)).

*Close votes can be of types: 'Close' (can be cast from inside or outside the review queue); and 'Do Not Close' (aka 'Leave Open'), besides 'Edit' or 'Skip' (all cast from inside the review queue).

---

**Proposal:**

Close a question (sooner than collecting 5 'Close' votes total), when there are 3 leading 'Close' votes (**'Close' votes cast both from inside and outside the review queue**).

By '3 leading Close votes' it is meant the first 3 votes cast to close a question without them being intervened by an edit (from inside or outside the review queue) or by a 'Leave Open' vote in the Close Votes review queue.

If there are edits or 'Leave Open' votes among first 3 'Close' votes, then continue applying current rule (5 votes threshold).

Some examples. Consider the following order/sequence of events in question:

- [1st vote: **'Close'**, 2nd vote: **'Close'**, 3rd vote: **'Close'**] --> **apply** the new rule (close sooner).
- [1st vote: 'Close', 2nd vote: **'Edit'** (from the queue), ... ] --> don't apply the new rule.
- [1st vote: 'Close', 2nd vote: 'Close', **edit occurs** (from outside the queue), ...] --> don't apply the new rule.
- [1st vote: 'Close', 2nd vote: 'Close', 3rd vote: **'Leave Open'**, ...] --> don't apply the new rule.
- [1st vote: 'Close', 2nd vote: **'Leave Open'**, ...] --> don't apply the new rule.
- etc.

Again, all types of 'Close' votes are valid (cast from inside or outside the Close Votes review queue).

---

**Reasoning**:

Most questions which receive 3 leading 'Close' votes end up getting closed anyway (Table 1). Why not redirect the surplus of review votes on currently approximate 8k questions waiting for review in the Close Votes review queue?

---

**Motivation for asking**:

Many close votes I have cast are aging away (i.e., expiring without the review process is completed). It feels my volunteer time trying to curate the site is not being fully availed. Actually, this is corroborated by [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1053164/site-activity-and-reviews?Weeks=60) (which is discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385023/declaring-a-review-strike-until-efficiency-improvements-are-implemented/385143#385143)) where up to 94% of close vote review tasks do not get completed. Amazing!

**Data showed we can be more efficient using close votes without being less or more rigorous in closing than we already are**. It could take effect immediately, without prejudice to other proposals of the like being implemented now or in the future.

---

**Data** (and method) for supporting proposal:

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/987014/amount-of-posts-closed-after-3-leading-close-votes-in-the-close-vote-review-queue) is a query which measures the amount of questions which ended up closed after it received 3 leading 'Close' votes in the Close Votes review queue**.

**I used data only from the review queue, because it is what is available in SEDE (i.e. wanted to use data from 'Close' votes cast outside the queue as well, but I don't think it is possible).

There are some highlights and limitations from this query, worth of listing:

- It considers as the **first** 'Close' vote, the one which triggered the review task (so, it is always the amount of votes in the `ReviewTaskResults` table + 1 'Close' vote). It happens a review task can be triggered by a close vote or a flag, and here we are considering a flag as a close vote (as if the user had the privilege). This is a conservative criterion because it bias the final result of the review towards not closing (one additional close vote is required if review task was triggered by flag). It seems there is no way to query in SEDE for reviews triggered only by close votes (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281406/can-i-query-the-sede-for-what-fraction-of-close-reviews-are-initiated-by-flags)).
- As mentioned above, the query is not considering 'Close' votes cast from outside the review queue, except the vote/flag which triggered the review (but they are part of this proposal). I am not sure how I could add those to the query above.
- The query also takes into account posts which had an 'Edit' close vote in the queue (this means if there was an 'Edit' vote among the leading ones, the post is not qualifying for a sooner closure). As mentioned before, it is also part of this proposal, when OP or someone else also edit the question outside from the queue (after one or more close votes are cast), the leading close votes rule should not be applied as well.
- The query is only considering review tasks which had at least 5 'Close' or 'Leave Open' votes total (i.e., 1 'Close' vote which triggered the review plus at least more 4 reviews in the queue). This is to minimize the effect of binding votes from moderators or users with tag gold badges.

**Results**:

Table 1. Proportion of closed questions as a function of number of leading 'Close' votes cast (the 1st one cast from outside the review queue, and the others from inside the queue).

```
Amount of leading 'Close' votes  Closed_(amount)  Closed_(% of total)
-------------------------------  ---------------  -------------------
                              2           164789                 83.6  
                              3           133819                 93.4
                              4           111451                 97.7
```

Table 1 means that if a question gets 3 leading 'Close' votes, chances of it ending up closed is 93.4% (4 leading 'Close' votes increases closing chances to almost 98%).

---

**Final considerations**

With that in mind, I believe the proposal could bring the following benefits:

- Redirection of surplus 'Close' votes to pending reviews in the Close Votes review queue.
- Reduction of time to closure from unclear, broad, opinion-based and off-topic questions preventing off-topic answers to be added.
- Increase in overall signal-to-noise ratio (by having more questions finished reviewing, not only because a surplus of votes is being created, but also due to a less amount of votes aging-away; hypothetically, this would have an exponential effect).
- It does not increase the burden of that very few users (<5% of reviewers) who are already hitting the vote cap at least sporadically (see, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science/320971#320971), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266500/proposal-to-make-close-votes-scale-with-rep#comment864675_266500), and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285438/we-need-more-close-votes/285486#285486)).

---

> But what about that other 2%-6%** of questions that despite having 4 or 3 leading 'Close' votes, ended up not being closed?

Let's transfer this cost to OPs, because recently they have already gained useful resources on their side: i) [Be Nice policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) [improved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review); ii) [New Contributor Indicator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314287/come-take-a-look-at-our-new-contributor-indicator?noredirect=1&lq=1); iii) [Ask Question Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live).

** Remembering, expect **lower** proportions of review tasks with result 'Leave Open' because data used in this question was biased towards not closing ('Close' votes outside the review queue were not considered; and 'Close' flags triggering reviews were considered, hence, pushing away the close votes count threshold).

Comment: Yes, but this overlooks scenarios in which the issue with the post which necessitated it being closed in the first place was fixed, thus prompting those who closed it to want to retract their close vote.  I feel like this is going to enable smaller groups of people to take more arbitrary voting actions than actually help curating the site.

Comment: some more interesting features are being discussed, like giving more weight to gold/silver badge holders votes on non-duplicate questions.

Comment: If it gets closed after 3 votes, and then the issue gets fixed, it can go into the reopen queue, just like when a question with 5 votes has been closed. Given the sheer number of close tasks that age away currently (resulting in lots of wasted effort), I think a somewhat larger reopen queue is worth a somewhat smaller close queue.

Comment: I would suggest adding the criteria that the close vote reasons must also match to ensure we're getting a good consensus on what is wrong with the post. (also... leave out all the review queue shtuff. If it gets edited at all before the 3rd, require 5.)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253324

Comment: I think you can replace all instances of "leading Close votes" with "consecutive Close votes" and then you won't have to explain what you mean by leading. Also, I think this should start out at 4 instead of 3. I'd also like to see some expanded gold badge privileges (e.g. Mjolnir for some reasons other than 'dupe').

Answer (score 14):

@YvetteColomb has pointed out   [Reduce the number of votes required to close a question to 4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4) which suggests reducing the threshold to 4 'Close' votes, no matter what.

In the spirit above (and from this question), if we started using 4 leading 'Close' votes (instead of 3), it would be even easier to support the proposal, since the fifth vote is nearly useless (Table 1).

From Table 1, we learned that 111.5k reviews ended up with a question closed after receiving 4 leading 'Close' votes, in which [9.7k were in 2018](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/990621/amount-of-questions-closed-after-4-leading-close-votes-in-the-close-vote-review-q). This means if we had saved one 'Close' vote per review in 2018, and then, had divided them by 5 (5 'Close' votes in a conservative scenario as if there were edits and 'Leave Open' votes in between 'Close' votes, thus requiring current rule for closing), we could have reviewed at least more 2k questions in the Close Votes review queue **which means 25% from current backlog**.

And this is based on data only from the queue, which as explained in question is biased towards not closing.

Answer (score 8):

I'm for this, because history. No, no data, but history. First lets go back to the start, when closing questions was introduced. Basically, you needed a single user to close a question, any question, for any reason. For duplicates, the system did absolutely nothing, so users just tried to be nice and provided a link.

Then as more users acquired the privilege, more disagreements there could be. Enter the close wars. During the close wars the amount of votes needed to close a question was incremented from 1 to 3, and later to 5. Changes were made to some close reasons, duplicates were improved. But, **the wars kept happening**. Disagreements were still there. Obviously, incrementing the number of votes needed weren't enough to stop wars. The only reason why today we require 5 votes to close a question is to prevent close wars.

But how about today. Do close wars keep happening with the same frequency as before? Nope, not at all. So what changed between then and now? Well, for one, SO gets many more questions, so there are many things asking for our attention instead of gripping about a single question. That might satisfy some as an explanation if they didn't know that we also have many more users than before, and there was a very small change that effected these wars in a fundamental way: you get only one vote, make it count.

Once the limits were introduced in the times you can vote to close/reopen, close wars almost disappeared, just by the nature that one of both sides runs out of steam. Sadly, we inherited the previous solutions that didn't cause any desirable effect on the problem, and in the long run seems to have cause unintended consequences.