# Why is the rate of positively scoring questions and answers steadily declining?

Tags: discussion, statistics, data-explorer

I looked at the number of newly created, non-deleted, non-closed questions and answers per month split by score (negative, zero, positive). ([SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1180980/questions-and-answers-per-month))

It looks like this:

[image]

The system [automatically deletes abandoned questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) older than 365 days with score <0 and no answers. I simulated this effect for 2019 by inspecting the jump in numbers of zero scored questions (red ellipse in figure above) and reduced the number of zero scored questions for 2019 by 33k for every month (the approximate number of questions that would get deleted automatically).

Then I can plot the number of total new questions and answers over time as well as splitting them into negative, zero and positive scores.

[image]

The overall behavior is that the number of questions and answers peaked at the beginning of 2014 and are slowly declining since then. Further I calculated some ratios. They look like

[image]

It seems that the ratio of answers to question roughly stays constant, in particular when only looking at answers and questions with positive scores. That means that the number of questions and answers both go down equally.

However there is a pronounced, steady downward trend in the portion of questions that have a positive score compared to all questions (80 % in 2010, 50% in 2015, 40% in 2018 of all questions have a positive score) and the same trend is visible for answers (80% in 2010, 60% in 2014, 50% in 2019 of all answers had a positive score). The two lower graphs of the last figure look remarkably similar, maybe there is a common cause of it, affecting questions and answers equally.

The question is why these fractions of positively received new questions or answers decreased steadily over the years?

It could be that the general interest in voting on questions and answers has decreased or it could be that the quality of questions and answers alike have decreased. Or it could be that questions and answers are more specific nowadays reducing the number of visitors.

It could also be that in the future some old questions and answer get more votes or get closed altering these graphs retroactively, but these effects usually are mostly concentrated in the first weeks of the life of a question or answer. But the trend is stable over 10 years, so I rather don't think that future voting and actions play a role here.

So what is a likely reason and can it backed up by statistics maybe?

I searched on meta with search terms "decrease question answer rate" but only found [Data science time! December 2018 and answer voting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377716/data-science-time-december-2018-and-answer-voting) and that only looks at a short time period in 2018.

Comment: Interesting to know would be how those downvoted questions look like. Are the voters just more strict in comparison to earlier questions or are most questions just already asked and many new ones are just repeating the old stuff (and then getting downvoted because of that). For example, most of my downvotes on questions are for obvious dupes.

Comment: Anecdotally speaking, these days I'm mostly closing and downvoting questions instead of answering them, since a lot lot *lot* of them are positively unanswerable these days. It's the rare occurrence nowadays to find a decent, answerable, non-duplicate question. My pet theory for that is that most questions have already been asked, and good programmers find and use them. The remaining rest are new students which through one way or another hear about SO as being *the place*, and they don't know and/or care about the quality standards and goals of the site.

Comment: @Tom Closed questions are exluded here. They may have been downvoted, but they were not closed as dupes yet. Interestingly there are ~15k new questions every month that get not deleted automatically (are not "abandoned") after a year, but have a negative score. That may be negatively scored questions with positively scored answers.

Comment: The overall participation level on Stackoverflow seems to decrease significantly, at  least in the tags I am active at.

Comment: This thread sounds relevant to me: https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1217838950494228480

Comment: Clearly it's because we're not welcoming enough. Answering questions isn't enough, maybe we should start paying people to ask questions?

Comment: So.... wait.... anyone of us who spends ANY time not answering question is evil now? really? "how dare you do data analytics to question stuff about to site to see if we can improve it!" feels like a.... freaking weird stance to take, and **completely** entitled. Who are some users to dictate to other users how to use their time? Jesus...

Comment: @KevinB if you are talking about ellipse in the first graph: "I simulated this effect for 2019 by inspecting the jump in numbers of zero scored questions *(red ellipse in figure above)* and reduced the number of zero scored questions for 2019 by 33k for every month"

Comment: I didn't see this mentioned yet, but I see no evidence that you have compensated for post age. *The longer a post has been on the site the higher the likely hood that it receives upvotes*. After all, most of the bad stuff has been weeded out already, and what remains has had much more time to be exposed to people with the same issue that could upvote these posts. It's absolutely *natural* to see a skew towards positive scores in older posts.

Comment: Next, while technology evolves and there are new areas to explore and ask questions about, there is a certain *saturation level* to account for, where most questions can be answered by the stuff that's already there. To me, 2014 is the point where we reached a tipping point, where most *basic, stable tech questions* had been answered.

Comment: There's a confounding factor you haven't compensated for: the longer a question or answer has been around, the greater a chance it has had to acquire a vote.  You really need to normalize for that in some way, such as measuring "score after one month".

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't compensate for age. I could do something like Mark suggests and get score after x days but that would not include late closing. I wrote in the question that I don't assume that ageing takes that long. But maybe it does. I would have thought that most of the ageing happens in the first weeks. If you have an idea how to control for ageing, I'd be happy to rerun the analysis.

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t, I don’t think there is enough info available on SEDE to reconstruct post score development. As for ageing: I receive upvotes across the full range of time I posted answers, questions will be the same. Community moderation is also not perfect so off-topic stuff can sometimes hang around for years before finally handled.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I probably could run the same set of queries on SEDE at different times (say a few months apart) and look how much the numbers of 10 years ago change. If they don't change, ageing might not be a big problem for long time scales (say years).

Comment: I would assume that aging wouldn't have a major impact on overall stats, considering only "useful" questions, questions people find via search, are ones that benefit from it.

Comment: I have spent countless hours on this over the years, posted dozens of times, analyzing the same data relations, even talking with Shog about what it all means, where it all came from, and how to make it better. Sorry that all you get is a comment, but I can't even right now as far as mustering a decades old research answer. There isn't just one facet to this. Many of the issues highlighted do play a roll. However, the end result is that quality is declining. Compared to the beginning, experts who ask questions now is absurd. That is what needs fixing, if you think that quality is a problem.

Comment: I would argue we address that issue by tuning the close reasons to allow for questions which experts would actually like to ask, which would be widely accepted by the community, but which are currently prevented due to close reasons not even meant for that type of post.

Comment: @TravisJ What kind of questions would experts like to ask? Maybe more open ended or more opinion based? I thought that the more expert you get the more specific questions become but otherwise not much changes.

Comment: @Trilarion - I honestly don't know what kind of questions experts would like to ask, I just know that is the direction we should go in. Definitely more open ended. The issue is, and it is true that it would be more specific, *however*, and this is the important caveat, intensely researched specific questions can still be rather open ended and "opinion based". The thing about opinion based though, is that it isn't always just based on teh feels, if you know what I mean, sometimes it requires a highly experienced person in order to provide valuable feedback from their observations.

Comment: @TravisJ When I think about typical work situations, when it's not about simple programming questions, it's mostly people running others through some of the harder problems they face and expecting not full blown solutions but expecting some sort of new impulses or error check. Typical answers would be "Have you tried X already?". It's super helpful but not sure if this is the right thing for public Q&A (how could others profit from it). Chat sounds more like the right place for such things.

Comment: @Trilarion - Chat is not a good fit, as it does not have wide adoption. Chat is good for people who are mostly at home wanting to not work. I strongly disagree that typical answers are going to be in the form of "have you tried X already", and strongly suggest a move towards a situation where answers can be in the form of "best practice dictates this type of approach". Seeing has how more and more developers are entering the field with lesser and lesser experience and background, it increasingly makes sense to provide this type of *expert* content at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, keep in mind, this is an actual solution that the community can take care of. We do not need any freaking management decisions in order to enact this. The close reason set was *designed* so that individual exchanges could define what was on topic for their site. Our moderation team has the ability to modify these without any employee intervening.

Comment: @TravisJ The community should discuss and take care of all the things it can take care of, even though I guess that the company can and will override any decision it doesn't like, see for example the control of the featured tag. I mostly want to know what went wrong with SO, why finding interesting new questions became more and more like the search for the needle in the haystack and what to do against it, here or somewhere else. As a potential conclusion from this question, one could say that there is demand for questions from experts and we could start a new discussion from there.

Comment: @Trilarion - Yup, I agree with all that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I posted an answer, then noticed your comment above. I credited you with the idea of the time effect - thank you!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't have any data to back this up, but with how many duplicate closings I do any given day I'd say the reason you are seeing this is because Stack Overflow has basically succeeded.

If you have a question and you're willing to do some research then you really don't need to ask a question anymore. I'm kind of an example of this.  I've written code in Crystal Reports, SQL, C++, C#, Java and Python and I've had numerous questions, but I've only actually asked 5 questions on the main site.  The reason?  I ask Google what I want to know, and generally 10-15 minutes later I have something I'm happy with and it's normally from a Stack Overflow Q&A.

Basically, we are in the [long tail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_tail).  There are not as many good questions to be asked, so fewer questions are getting upvoted.  There is also the case that many highly duplicated questions get downvoted these days because they are trivial to look up but aren't, which is wasting our time.

Comment: I concur. SO is basically saturated, *and in addition* the word has now gotten round to a new generation of newbies who were not here in the founding stages, have no idea how SO is supposed to work and think about it in terms of Reddit.

Comment: Sounds plausible for the case of questions, but why is there the same trend for answers? Do not as good questions result in not as good answers as well? The statistics in the question already excludes deleted or closed questions.

Comment: @Trilarion From what I've seen, lower quality question tend to attract lower quality answers.  There is also the case where people like to down vote answers to off topic questions as "punishment" but as you've said closed questions are excluded so that shouldn't be a factor.

Comment: I'm not sure long tail describes this situation. There will always be new frameworks and new languages, new techniques and packages, whose workings are as poorly documented or confusing as ever. What is happening is that we've worked through an amount of the backlog. There are still tasks being added.

Answer (score 10):

This answer may be bad because it is based on experience instead of data. But still:

In the tag I frequent most, Java, the quality of questions and answers seems to steadily decline for some time now.

New users tend to post more assignments without any attempt or research, low quality posts that repeat text to get past the quality check, and questions that have been asked a bazillion times before (I'm looking at you, NullPointerException, String#equals and pyramid printing patterns).

Even with the necessary close vote number changing from 5 to 3, questions that are low quality, duplicates or off-topic often don't get closed fast enough, so they collect (again, often quickly drafted or low-quality) answers.

I don't know about other tags, and, like I said, this is not backed by data, it's just my observation. So, yes, I believe the quality is declining.

Comment: How much of this is just you having gained more experience and so can recognise bad questions much more easily? Take into account that bad questions *tend* to be weeded out, over time, slowly. So it's hard to find evidence for *old* bad questions, and all the bad stuff starts to *look* recent and new.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have certainly gained more experience and confidence in closing regarding dupes and off-topics (although I lurked for a year before joining and was pretty consistent from the start). But the amount of plain bad questions (gimme-the-code), paired with a sense of entitlement and often due dates, has definitely increased. I can now scroll through pages of new Java questions that are very bad. I can hardly find stuff completely or interesting enough to answer.

Answer (score 5):

> It could also be that in the future some old questions and answer get
>   more votes or get closed altering these graphs retroactively, but
>   these effects usually are mostly concentrated in the first weeks of
>   the life of a question or answer. But the trend is stable over 10
>   years, so I rather don't think that future voting and actions play a
>   role here.

Older questions and older answers *by definition* had a longer time during which they could be acted upon: voted up, voted down, edited, closed, deleted, protected. These actions can skew the results you see on the plots. **In fact, voting, editing, closing, deletion, protection, etc are mechanisms carefully designed and optimized over the years to increase the value and *quality* of questions and answers.** (EDIT: after posting this, I noticed a comment above from @MartijnPieters, where he says something similar, so the credit for the time effects should go to him.)

**Any analysis of quality should start with validating by human curators any of these easy to obtain, SQL-based so called "quality" metrics.  Otherwise, the data are subject to a massive selection bias.**

The trends shown can be detected over a short time period, such as a year, as can be seen on the plots. An obvious and not too difficult experiment, for users with enough reputation, is to measure quality trend over the recent 12 months, in a *double-blind* way by randomizing questions and answers, **including the closed and deleted ones**, *stripping dates*, and having **actual human experts** rate them.

> It could be [...] that the quality of questions and answers alike have
>   decreased.

It could be... But the data does not exclude a much more obvious explanation. The fact that the rate of decrease of the so called "quality" is about the same for both questions and answers suggests some confounding effect common to *both* of these. This confounder is most likely selection bias due to different time periods available for quality improvement by voting, editing, closing, deletion, protection, etc.

---

**FAQs:**

Q: What selection bias? Most of the voting occurs soon after posting.
A: I vote on old posts if I find them useful (or not). I also edit them. I doubt I am the only person doing so on SO. Just look at the late queues!

Q: I still do not believe in selection bias. Show me the money!
A: Watch the new questions on SO (or any SE site) closely. You will likely see a lot of questions downvoted or not as upvoted as they could have been with comments such as "[possible] duplicate of `<insert your somewhat related 2012 question here>`". Note that the new question could be legitimate, and thus it is not actually closed as a dupe. It just hobbles on to become one of those `0` or `-1` scored questions - all because it sounded vaguely familiar to someone. Meanwhile, the 2012 question will live on and might even get upvotes due to the link in the comment under the new question.

Q: What about the effect of `X` on quality?
A: Yes, most likely I overlooked a ton of other mechanisms by which quality changes with age, both up and down. **Comments** may have a positive effect. Also, **search engines** are probably more likely to show earlier posts due to them more likely to be linked to from other sites (although the better search engines may correct for this effect). In fact, I often have to limit Google search results to the recent N years to remove the earlier questions (sometimes massively upvoted back in yonder times, but now outdated due to new software releases).

Comment: Even with the mechanisms stripped, the pattern persists. However, I do agree with your actual human expert rating idea.

Answer (score 4):

This is only a guess, I can't even begin to come up with how to pull up data for it, but my general theory on why this is happening and why there's been such a push over the past few years for people to ask more questions, is that as more questions are asked and answered, there are less unanswered questions to be asked. Therefore, there needs to be a larger and larger input of questions to overcome the worsening signal/noise ratio year over year.

The less good, unanswered questions there are to ask, the more questions that need to be input into the system to receive the same number of good unanswered questions in need of quality answers over a given period.

Of course... a simpler alternative would be to just hide the problem by alienating the people who care about quality and thus reduce the amount of low quality posts that end up showing up as low quality posts.

Comment: The number of questions is going down, but unfortunately it's mostly the number of positively received questions (the good ones). I fully agree with your last paragraph. Score is not equal to quality. If we would all stop downvoting, quality would not go up, it would go down.

Answer (score -19):

The Wikipedia effect. Most of the good questions have been asked, increasingly gate keepers try to narrow scope and mark everything as a duplicate if it's vaguely similar to one of the thousands of previous questions on the topic etc.

Comment: Is there maybe a reference available to the Wikipedia effect or could you give a few more sentences explanation? I'm not sure what it is exactly. Also what do you think is the most important factor: good questions already been asked, narrowing down of scope or imprecise duplicate closing, or every of these reasons equally important?