# Why are we using Meta for these four things?

Tags: discussion, meta, bug-reporting-process, feature-request-process

Why are we using Meta for these four things?

- [support](/questions/tagged/support), which indicates a request for assistance with one of the site's features.
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), denoting a reproducible problem on the site that you believe is due to a mistake, malfunction, or programming error
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), for a proposal for a new feature on the site, or requests a change to an existing feature.
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), for posts that may not have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and are often subjective. If it's not a bug or feature request, it is probably a discussion.

I am going to guess that this has been asked before, but my search attempts failed to find the duplicate.

I think `[support]` and `[bug]` should be separated from `[feature-request]` and `[discussion]`.

If someone is asking for help, the last thing they need is for someone to down-vote their request. If someone is reporting a defect, down-voting seems like a bizarre response.

I can see how voting is useful for `[feature-request]` and `[discussion]`, but it really seems counter-productive for the other tags.

I really think that people underestimate the negative emotional impact of down-voting.

Comment: Not a duplicate but an interesting discussion on meta stack exchange about this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328160/does-meta-have-to-mean-murder

Comment: What else would you use?

Comment: @Cerbrus Is there some really good reason that we are reusing a question-and-answer interface for these things?

Comment: (Development) costs. Maintainance. Hosting.

Comment: @Cerbrus Are you saying Stack Exchange Inc. does not have money to add features to the site?

Comment: I'm saying they'd have to build a new site, if they want to do it properly.

Comment: Some history of it: [Should meta.stackoverflow.com replace uservoice.com?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1) and to the extent of [How is question voting intended on meta? Can Meta really replace UserVoice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3891/241919)

Comment: @DavidCullen probably doesn't want to add features that aren't part of the core focus - Q&A format. Jeff left *because* he was making a discussion platform. I agree that the Q&A is not really appropriate - CodeReview is stuck with this as well when it's not very natural or useful format but...it is what it is, I guess. Besides, a `[bug]` being downvoted might mean the community doesn't think it's important.

Comment: @davidcullen the blog post introducing meta from 2009 calls it an experiment. Practically speaking I don’t believe there have ever been resources tied to iterating on that experiment or determining whether it’s a failed experiment or not. There have been minor features around the edges but never a holistic “is a Q&A platform really the best software for community to discuss issues.”

Comment: @Cerbrus For support, I might use a help desk. For defect reports, I might use a defect tracking system. For feature requests, I might silently divert them to the bitbucket. For discussion, I might use a discussion system. I find it astonishing that on a web site for software professionals, the best idea for handling these different items was to overload a system that was designed for something else. Maybe in the early years, that made sense. The idea that it was never questioned since then is quite startling to me.

Comment: What makes you think it was never questioned? We all know Meta isn’t that good for these things.

Comment: @Cerbrus The fact that this isn't a duplicate might have led me to believe it wasn't recently questioned. And who's "we"? I didn't know. I didn't even realize until recently that meta was used for all of these things. I always thought meta was used to discuss Stack Overflow and to get rid of tags.

Comment: It's come up quite often that we need a proper bug tracker, and a proper support system...

Comment: For discussions and feature requests, voting means agreement/disagreement, not high quality/low quality.

Answer (score 8):

While I agree that meta is misused for some of these purposes, I don't quite agree with which ones:

I can understand [support](/questions/tagged/support) being fielded here, since it makes sense to crowd-source most of these requests. Support can be given by the regular community users or elected moderators. For support beyond that, users should be directed to the contact-form, as they usually are.

For [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), it's a completely different matter. SE should have a proper tracker for their developers to deal directly and interact with the community there. The community doesn't need to be involved in this, beyond "voting" to indicate "we'd like this to be prioritized", and maybe commenting. This is nothing new nor original, it's been invented many times over and is used all around by many, many companies.

I'm pretty sure SE employees mentioned that they are aware of this *"we lack a proper tracker"* issue, but I can't find the appropriate posts right now.

Comment: [tag:bug]s should certainly go into a bug tracker, but [tag:feature-request]s often involve more or less substantial changes to the platform, in which the community should have and wants to have a say. Of course nowadays this often ends in a draw and nothing being done since nobody can come to a consensus. Typical design by committee situation.

Comment: @deceze Most of the products I use, have the same system to track FRs and bugs, and it makes sense to me. Meta could be left to _discuss_ potential FRs, not to actually submit/track them. It would make more sense that way, IMO.

Comment: Yes, once an FR actually makes it into the "accepted" stage, it should go into a company internal tracking tool. And I'm sure it is. I doubt the mothership is working on anything without it going through [some proper tracker.](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) The thing is that hardly anything makes it to the "accepted" stage if it goes through a discussion first, so that's all somewhat moot. And random users being able to submit FRs directly into the company internal tracker is maybe not a good idea if it involves substantial platform changes.

Comment: Again, I do not quite agree. I believe a **public** tracker, both for bugs and FRs works fine. Many companies do have them. E.g. [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38995). Only the employees can change status, mark as other tickets as related, etc. The community can vote and/or comment, but in the end the having the whole Q&A process/format for every single FR seems inadequate to me.

Comment: Then probably a lot of discussion would be happening on that tracker, which defeats the purpose and clogs up actual tools used for development, which will make developers very unhappy. Let the discussion happen here, and if something makes it through, it should be handled invisibly from the public henceforth.

Comment: I've personally used a public (but internal) tracker which handled both feature requests & bugs (most of them actually) - it shouldn't be hard to assign different priority & tracking tags to each to separate them. I do except that they have so much legacy code & policy tangled up in this that they cannot easily untangle it and here we are

Answer (score 2):

My impression on this is that Stack Exchange Q/A is a very flexible format that can suit more or less all the uses of meta but none of them quite right. Maybe support is the closest: you ask "how do I do this?" and you get "you do it like this". But still is not exactly right since, unlike in SO, support questions are not so much required to be useful for the future and can be much more case-specific. The result is that the mechanics of the site have a different meaning, usage or applicability depending on the "question", in something of a tacit but fluid consensus.

I have written down my current understanding of the site, with the shortcomings that I see in it and possible alternatives.

#### [support](/questions/tagged/support)

- **Question:** "I have this problem using the site" / "I do not know how to do this"
- **Answer:** "Here is how you can solve or do that"
- **Upvote:** "I have this problem too" / "I think this is an important or interesting problem"
- **Downvote:** "You did not do any effort to solve this" / "The formulation of your question is poor or unclear"
- **Shortcomings:** Meaning of votes may not be clear for the OP or even useful in general. In most cases, support questions could be "closed" forever after they are resolved, as once the person solves the specific issue there is no need to keep the question alive for more answers, edits or votes.
- **Alternative:** Q/A, but a bit more oriented to product support, or just a standard support system like Zendesk.

#### [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

- **Question:** "There is this error in the site"
- **Answer:** "We have solved the bug" / "It was not a bug"
- **Upvote:** "I am affected by this error too" / "I think this is an important error"
- **Downvote:** "This is not actually an error" / "I am okay with how it works currently"
- **Shortcomings:** No tracking information for the bug about the actual awareness of the company, the status (investigating/accepted/rejected/...) or the planned action. No ability to "watch" or "subscribe" to issue updates. Answer comes at the end of the resolution process.
- **Alternative:** Issue tracking system with votes.

#### [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

- **Question:** "I want this to change on the site"
- **Answer:** "We will do that" / "We will not do that"
- **Upvote:** "I want this too"
- **Downvote:** "I do not want this"
- **Shortcomings:** Similar to bugs.
- **Alternative:** Issue tracking system with votes.

#### [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

- **Question:** "What do you think of this"
- **Answer:** "This is my opinion on this"
- **Upvote:** "I agree with it" / "I think this is an interesting discussion"
- **Downvote:** "I do not agree with this" / "This is not an interesting discussion"
- **Shortcomings:** Opinions are scattered around comments and answers. No ability to have more extended discussion, following different threads. Impractical unstructured streams of comments. For things like burnination, no clear information on progress or outcome resulting from the discussion. Not clear when the discussion is considered "closed".
- **Alternative:** Forum / Discourse / ???

#### Company announcements

This are under discussion (e.g. [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376259)) but I think they are quite different.

- **Question:** "See this we wanted to tell you"
- **Answer:** "This is what I think of this announcement"
- **Upvote:** "I like this"
- **Downvote:** "I do not like this"
- **Shortcomings:** Unclear what the purpose of answers are here, or whether they are different from comments besides extension. Unclear why this is presented here and not in the blog. Downvotes not very useful by themselves (better say what exactly you do not like and why).
- **Alternative:** Blog with comments / Reddit-like / ...

This is all my view and understanding, of course, which may be wrong in many things. But I think most people would agree that there are at least some things that just do not fit very well in meta Q/A. Why the insistence in fitting everything in here, then? Well, if I know one thing about meta users is that they like their Q/A, so why shoehorn it into everything, as some kind of Swiss army knife of communication, so you can use the same mechanics we have come to love appreciate to deal with every problem in the world. It also concentrates about all things SO into a single site.

I am not saying this or that would be the better, but I think there is diversity about what each of the mechanics mean for each user in meta. Maybe it is okay to stick Q/A into everything, but maybe there should be more guidance about what one should expect in each case, specially if meta wants to attract more users and become more representative of the community. I personally am a relatively seasoned SO user (mostly answering, not in moderation) and I still feel there is something of a barrier to entry in meta.

Comment: Regarding the shortcomings of bugs and feature-requests we have several tags that give information about the status i.e. [meta-tag:status-bydesign] or [meta-tag:status-completed]

Comment: @Turamarth Yes, that is true, although again it is abusing a Q/A feature to compensate for the lack of another feature. It is not obvious how it works, specially for less experienced meta users, and I cannot "watch" these updates. But anyway, as I said it may be good enough as it is, I just mean meta feels like a very special kind of Q/A with its own idiosyncrasies that may appear unnatural or difficult to grasp for outsiders.

Comment: "No ability to "watch" or "subscribe" to issue updates." You can favorite a question to be updated about changes. "Answer comes at the end of the resolution process." That's completely up to employees; they recently went through `feature-request`s and tagged some as `status-review`, which is an interim status. The same could be done for `bug`s.