# What is the mission of Meta, as a community?

Tags: discussion, meta, stack-exchange

In [this question,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393552) statements of Stack Overflow's mission by [Joel Spolsky](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) and [Prashanth Chandrasekar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/11741668/pchandrasekar) are quoted:

> - For many years now our founder Joel and others have said our mission is: 
>     "Helping developers write the script of the future."
> - Recently our new CEO updated the mission statement: 
>     "Helping write the script of the future by serving developers and technical workers."

There are several other questions on Meta asking what Stack Overflow's mission is, and their answers do not align with these statements.

- [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382032/3474) (from the site [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)):

  > [W]e're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming."
- [Here:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254973/3474)

  > Core ideas where a site that's strictly Q+A, no chit-chat or discussion, just questions and answers strictly separated.
- [Here:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/3474)

  > The primary purpose is to build a repository of questions and answers.

From my limited sampling of such answers and the voting, it seems that most members of the meta community have a different idea about the mission of Stack Overflow than the corporate officers of Stack Exchange, Inc.

*Do active members of Meta have a mission? What is it?*

You might address these related questions in your answer: Does the corporate mission statement have a meaning? Does the community mission differ from Stack Exchange's mission? If so, is that appropriate?

Comment: _"Helping write the script of the future by serving developers and technical workers."_ is vague and sounds like the job of a waiter at Google's canteen. But it's so vague that it's not incompatible with other statements

Comment: Isn't the mission of Meta to give valuable feedback, to propose new and discuss existing rules as well as represent the stake of the users to the company, at least of everyone who wants to take part in Meta? This has been discussed somewhere else before most probably, I think.

Comment: Could I ask on meta what the script of the future is or would my question be closed as needs more clarity?

Comment: You asked about meta's goal, but then address main's goal. There seems to be a blurring of lines here. Are you curious about discussing the mission of Stack Overflow, or about discussing the mission of meta?

Comment: @TravisJ I am asking about our mission as a group of people, not the purpose of the meta web site as a tool used by that group. Yes, I think this is most interesting viewed in relation to the mission of the main site... if our mission is different or doesn't at least support the mission of SO, what are we doing? Or what is SO doing? In order measure that alignment, I want to know if Meta has a clear sense of mission.

Comment: @TravisJ The former is closer to what I am after. There wouldn't be a Meta without the main site, right? So whatever this group is striving for, I presume, will impact the main site.

Comment: I didn't really think too much about the bafflegab in the corporation "mission statements," but when I stopped to look at the difference between Spolsky and Chandrasekhar's versions, I think there is a very significant difference: Spolsky wanted to empower developers (to write the script of the future, whatever that means). Chandrasekhar wants SE to write the script.

Comment: The likely meaning of this "mission change" is this: "We will kill the small SE sites, merging their content into the SO, in order to boost our terrible stats".

Comment: I thought the mission was Questions Using One-line for Random Answers

Comment: Just out of curiosity: is the assumption here that one is not a member of the "StackOverflow community" unless one participates actively in Meta?

Comment: Funny enough, it's for asking questions like what the mission of meta is.  Or would that be "Meta Meta SO"?

Comment: @rici I don't think this is the assumption. Asking for what do you think the mission of meta is if you don't take part in meta, is probably just seen as not constructive. Although I wonder if meta has a mission too for those that only passively consume the content. That's what the company looked at recently and found that there are 10x more readers than writers on meta.

Comment: @trilarion: several of the answers here only identify the corporate mission and the meta mission, which leads me to wonder whether metazens think that the rest of SO's user community is, in fact, a community, with or without a mission, a culture or a network of interpersonal relationships. Had anyone asked me whether I considered myself a part of the SO community, I would have answered "yes" without reservations, but I'm not even one of the 10/11 who read and don't write; I read meta only when distracted by clickbait, which is not often. And this is my longest contribution in seven years.

Comment: @rici I think that's a good question. You could ask it. If you ask me I'd say that of course there are different communities within communities here and it's never really clear what is what. We all interact on the main site by asking, answering, commenting, voting, closing or just reading and that makes something with us. Without some common aim that would not work or would it?

Comment: Not the same question, or maybe even strongly related, but reminds me of this other one [Why are we using Meta for these four things?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388019/1782792)

Comment: I stopped trying to be active on Meta sometime in 2009, and although I answer questions on main, I disagree with the attempt to minimize discussion.  I suppose, for me, the purpose of meta would have been to persuade the website to encourage discussion rather than squelch it, but that is clearly the opposite of the site's goal.  I've been happy to see SO's popularity grow, but feel that the lack of discussion has impeded the development of community as a community.  Just my $.02.  Now I'll go back to not reading meta.

Comment: @rici No, that's not my assumption here. It sounds like I'm more like you. I've often felt like Meta was often not a good representation of many core contributors on the main site. But I am interested in how this community sees itself, and its relationship to the corporate objectives.

Comment: @erickson - Before the meta splits, when it was just mSO, there was a far larger representation here with regards to content creators.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - Out of curiosity, how would you scope discussion with regards to SO main, and how would that be different from Software Engineering SE (formerly Programmers SE).

Comment: @TravisJ I'm not really familiar with Software Engineering SE.  I recall that several years ago I tried to post some questions on Programmers that were geared toward starting a discussion on best practices, and the questions were jumped on as being too vague or the like, so I lost interest.  The discussions on usenet groups were extremely beneficial, and I think SO is missing a lot of that flavor.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - Even though you haven't been actively participating on meta, that doesn't mean there hasn't been a large amount of push in the direction of allowing more subjective questions, altering close votes to encourage higher quality questions, or refining current closure to not cut off quality content. The problem is that, on meta, without voices like yours and other important content creators, the balance of discourse falls to those who are not focused on creating content.

Comment: I think people come to StackOverflow because they want answers to questions. If you gave them a script of the future, they would say thanks, but no thanks. If all you gave them was help to write their own script of the future, they'd think you were bonkers.

Comment: It's not clear to me what a "script of the future" is. Especially given the site's topic, is it in the programming sense, or the writing/directorial sense, or some play on words of both that doesn't need to be there and is just trying to be clever?

Comment: I think your question is an answer to that actually. You're seeking clarity, promoting discussion and this may or may not shape the way the website is used and/or moderated. Whereas what the main site is about is how to append an object to an array in Python.

Comment: I've just read that question again and it leaves me totally bewildered. Meta is a place for discussion, and a place for discussion should not have a mission. You can refer to the people who meet in this place as a community if you wish, but to me the very idea that they come here because they share a mission is anathema. In many cases they come here to discuss their differences, and the meeting place exists to enable that.

Comment: To me this question is pretty unclear. The title ask for a mission of Meta (Meta Stack Overflow, I assume) while the body text is mainly addressing the mission of Stack Overflow. So when the question is: "Do active members of Meta have a mission?" - I'm not sure whether the question is about a Meta-SO mission or a SO mission. In my mind those are very different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I don't see how that's a duplicate - the answers there are all focused on *how* Meta works, nothing about the goals of Meta's community.

Comment: I would have thought it's the mission of Meta to get Monica reinstated. :-p *grabs handy shield to protect from onslaught of paper balls*

Comment: Personally, I though the Mission of Meta was to downvote and belittle anyone who asks a question on Meta that isn't with the "in" crowd on Meta -- at least that is what the mission appears to be from someone on the outside. I found this curious from a organization that relies on the contributions from its members and users to exist. The same in changing the close messages on SO. The new close messages no longer provide any guidance for what SE site is the correct site and come across as very unwelcoming. And that one word "Unwelcoming" is contrary to what Meta should be.

Answer (score 73):

To be fair, the principal mission of the Meta users largely aligned with the original mission, which was to create a library of detailed answers to every programming question.

The company now seeks to change that - which is fine - but I'm not convinced that there's enough buy-in from the Meta community to truly realize that.

If the mission of the company and Meta diverge in a *significant* way, then we are truly screwed.  In that context, appropriateness is thrown out the window since now we have culture being pushed from the top down.

Comment: Careful. Meaningless jargon like “buy-in” is beginning to pervade your answers. :-)

Comment: I like how you keep talking as if this diverging is still to come. The future is already happening...

Comment: @CodyGray: We're writing the script for the future by elucidating innovative ideas and providing value-added propositions to our stakeholders for maximizing profit potential.

Comment: I thought we were writing the script for the future by generating and curating high-quality answers to programming questions, answers that contain copy-paste ready code, which programmers of the future will paste into environments that are literally running the world.

Comment: "to create a library of detailed answers to every programming question" wasn't the entirety of the original mission. It was just the goal of the byproduct.

Comment: I thought for sure someone would have included "Making the world a better place..."  :)

Comment: @CodyGray "answers that contain copy-paste ready code" - they _don't_ though, because the great collective groupthink of meta vehemently rejected the permissive MIT content license and then a copyleft license (CC-BY-SA) got shoved down everyone's throat instead. Woe unto anyone who thinks they can copy/paste code from SO into any sort of proprietary codebase and not risk landing in hot water with their company's legal department/compliance officer. If SE corporate is finally taking action to reign in meta's insular, clique-y influence on the platform that's a good thing in my book.

Comment: @aroth Stack Exchange content has *never* been permissively, copy-left licensed, either via MIT or any other license. **Since day one, posts here have *always* been licensed under CC by-SA**, with the important part being "SA", or "attribution required". Note the "attribution required" blog post by Jeff Atwood that has been linked in the footer of Stack Overflow nearly since launch. You absolutely cannot copy-paste code from SO into a proprietary code base without giving attribution to the original author of the code, and never have been able to. My comment in that sense was tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @aroth not sure, if I recall correctly some of us were just unhappy with having our contributions "retroactively" changed to MIT. Which is not possible unless explicitly granted by the copyright holder, i.e. me. In fact, I used to triple license my contributions under CC-BY-SA, MIT and public domain. (Under jurisdictions where public domain is applicable.)

Comment: By the way, "realize" as in understanding, or as in "help making a reality"? @Makoto

Comment: "The company now seeks to change that - which is fine..." I understand acknowledging they have the right to do so, but that doesn't really make it "fine." It's quite a big problem, not only for us but also for the people who depend on this site to generate useful content.

Comment: @Prof.Falkencontractbreached - the latter.

Comment: @CodyGray "with the important part being "SA", or "attribution required" - It's the **BY** which requires attribution. And if the license was just CC-BY then that would _probably_ satisfy most proprietary use-cases. However what the **SA** actually means is "Share Alike", which effectively prohibits proprietary use. Or [as Creative Commons puts it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license), **SA** means: `Licensees may distribute derivative works only under a license identical to the license that governs the original work. (See also copyleft.)`.  The SA makes it copyleft.

Answer (score 67):

## Meta is here to discuss how to use the main site

Serious question: is [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) on-topic for Stack Overflow? Now, Docker is a way to do DevOps (server configs, etc.), but it's also a programming tool. As such [a former community manager declared it on-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380590/2370483).

Without Meta, discussions like this wouldn't be possible. You need a place to talk about **how to use the site**, but doing so on the site itself would merely **add noise**. As such, Meta operates differently from the main site

- There's no reputation on Meta (except Meta.SE) because votes represent agreement or disagreement
- Chit-chat is somewhat tolerated
- Thresholds for greying and community deletion are higher (-1 main site answers, [-8 for Meta answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268071/2370483))

Comment: The need for those three operational differences somewhat exposes how suboptimal it is to shoehorn the full spectrum of discussions necessary for community governance of the Q&A site into a Q&A format itself...

Comment: This answer fits my general thoughts on meta's purpose. I would say it's also here to help steer users in the right direction when they find their interactions with the site aren't fitting with expectations. On meta, there are probably hundreds of questions about "Why was my question closed?" Right now responding to those questions is an effort spread out over the whole community, but imagine if all that went into a ticketing system where SO employees responded directly. Answers to those would probably become a set of canned responses instead of any sort of individualized or useful feedback.

Answer (score 38):

**Main's Mission**

Main's mission has been extensively discussed, and has also been pretty straightforward for a long time.

Get people answers to their questions, ensure that content can stand the test of time.

This mission has been wrapped in all sorts of slogan over the years.

**Meta's Interpretation**

There is a balance to be struck, between getting people answers and ensuring that content stands the test of time. In this balance, there are groups which will lobby in each directions behalf.

Despite all the labels, meta is not a congruent group.

There are those who believe that the balance should sway one way or another. In addition, there are developments which alter the system to go one way or another that will change any given user's perspective.

**Meta's Mission**

Meta's mission is to ensure the highest amount of success possible for Stack Overflow. If something goes wrong, you will hear about it on meta. If things are doing great, you will hear about it on meta.

Just because certain users may disagree with where the balance currently is, which direction it should go, or where it should ideally reside, does not mean they are not all still working together to move Stack Overflow towards increasing success.

**"Mission statements"**

"Helping write the script of the future by serving developers and technical workers" is not a mission statement. It is a slogan. It sounds nice, but to get to an analogy I have already used before, Nike's mission statement isn't "Just Do It.". Nike's actual mission statement is to "Bring inspiration and innovation to every athlete in the world" and they quantify that by explaining what they are doing which is actionable.

Despite the current focus on the script of the future phrasing itself, to be fair, the new CEO does lay out not only what is actionable but what the goals are that define future actions for Stack Overflow.

If you are curious what Stack Overflow's mission is, please re-read https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/21/scripting-the-future-of-stack-2020-plans-vision/, it is literally all laid out there.

The main issue with this updated mission is that most of meta has defined the balance of the aforementioned system (answers vs. repository) somewhere in the middle (for example, let's call the range between 40%-60%); however, now the seeming balance being struck is at the 10% mark, where the CEO has effectively weighed in with a supervote overriding the community.

This in itself isn't problematic, after all, the CEO of tech companies are generally very in tune with the product they started, built, and put their blood, sweat and tears into... except that isn't the case here.

**Words vs Actions**

Luckily so far, the system itself is not fundamentally altered, and the overall ecosystem is still intact. In other words, this has so far just been talk, which is good, because fundamentally altering such a system without strong justification is dangerous to the integrity of the system.

The only action seen so far by the community in general has been to witness all of the people being removed who were familiar with possible outcomes of fundamentally altering the system. That this is just coincidence remains to be seen, as it is possible other more tumultuous members of the team may have played a role.

**[Stack Overflow is *you*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/11/25/stack-overflow-is-you/)**

> This is the scary part, the great leap of faith that Stack Overflow is predicated on: **trusting your fellow programmers**. The programmers who choose to participate in Stack Overflow are the “secret sauce” that makes it work. *You* are the reason I continue to believe in developer community as the greatest source of learning and growth. *You* are the reason I continue to get so many positive emails and testimonials about Stack Overflow. I can’t take credit for that. But you can.
>
> I learned the collective power of my fellow programmers long ago writing on Coding Horror. The community is far, far smarter than I will ever be. All I can ask — all any of us can ask — is to help each other along the path.
>
> - Jeff Atwood, Co-Founder Stack Overflow

All of this said, please keep in mind, Meta is a collective power. I do not speak for anyone on meta, only myself, and the same is of any other user here. We are just trying to work together to make things better.

Comment: Would you say that Meta is a bit like a union of the users? It's open to everyone and it allows users to organize themselves.

Comment: @Trilarion - It is open to everyone, although I am not sure it really offers many tools for actually organizing. I think that isn't a bad analogy, but it probably does break down in places.

Comment: @Trilarion: One important way in which this analogy breaks down, is that unions are very strongly protected by law, at least in my jurisdiction. Firing someone for speaking up at a union meeting and firing someone for speaking up for the union would be so illegal that not even the most ruthless manager or lawyer would even dare to dream about it, let alone talk about it or even do it. Also, unions have *real* power, again protected by law, they have a mandate for negotiating with the company, also protected by law.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You're right, there is no protection by law here and additionally unions are only for employees - you can hardly negotiate a salary if you don't get one. But still I like to think of meta as a union because it's the idea that's so similar, i.e. have an organization and representation of workers and I feel like I'm doing work here, so I must be a worker and this is my representation towards the company.

Comment: @Trilarion The meta evolved its own "acceptable" *opinion standards*, which are ortohogonal to the success of the site (and contradicting to the success of the site network). Beside that, the company is simply incompetent to handle its own success, its structural cause is likely [Peters' Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_principle). On these reasons, unfortunately I can't predict any good in the future for the site(s).

Comment: Main's mission hasn't been that since 2014. Now it's to get eyeballs to make advertising money.

Comment: @Ben - Gotta keep the lights on. What you say does have some truth though, seemingly there are people who view this entire endeavor as just buyers and sellers without realizing it is much more than that.

Comment: @TravisJ I'm really referring to the change in policy from "quality first", to "engagement and welcomingness" - i.e. volume. It seems every question is a duplicate now, gets multiple upvotes, and gets multiple answers, each of which gets multiple upvotes. Rep earned after 2014 is a completely different currency.

Comment: @Ben - I don't really agree with that, nor the assertion that quality and welcoming are mutually exclusive. With regards to the overall history of the welcoming push, it was mostly just a initiative to make the closure process more straightforward to users, as many felt disenfranchised from the way it was being done before. That it morphed into something else happened for a plurality of reasons, some beyond the company's control. With regards to answers and votes, we are actually at a historical low of answers posted per question.

Comment: @TravisJ only one thing can be top priority. . . . SO is now full of duplicate questions and trivial questions. Each gets multiple upvotes. Each gets multiple answers. Each answer gets multiple upvotes. It's just a big rep farm. You only have to look too see it. That's all. Just look. . . .  That's what engagement over quality looks like.

Comment: @Ben - Quality and welcoming are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @TravisJ You already said that. I already said I disagree.

Comment: @Ben - You seemed to have ignored the fact that the data contradicts your original assertion. No new points were raised in your response, so I simply repeated myself. Quality and welcoming are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @TravisJ You have been heard. I disagree. If you feel I have made no new points, and have no new points yourself, then there is no need to respond.

Comment: @Ben - I wish you had taken that advice when you made your comment simply repeating your original assertion.

Answer (score 9):

Companies can have a mission much more easily than a community of volunteers. They have a hierarchy and a mission can be decided at the top of the hierarchy and then be enforced.

For a community of volunteers like the users of Stack Overflow or the users of Stack Overflow that are also on meta, it's more complicated. There is no hierarchy (except moderators maybe), people are volunteering their time and can stop doing it at anytime. It's reasonable to assume that they have a bunch of somewhat aligned common goals, but that's it.

> Do active members of Meta have a mission? What is it?

Therefore the answer is: not only one mission, but lots of missions. Judging by the typical answers given and the voting patterns, a majority of meta users clearly prefers something like the original "building a Q&A knowledge base" mission. See for example [Does the company still want this to be a library of knowledge?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388384/does-the-company-still-want-this-to-be-a-library-of-knowledge). A minority of meta users however might also be okay with a more supporting and teaching role. It's not a totally homogeneous community.

> Does the corporate mission statement have a meaning?

I cannot really translate the current mission of the company to a lot of meaning; it seems to have a very wide scope. I guess that they want to have a very broad mission that kind of includes the original mission and much, much more. The new mission mostly tells me that they want to be an essential part of programming in general but it doesn't really tell me how and I cannot really imagine how.

> Does the community mission differ from Stack Exchange's mission? If so, is that appropriate?

Yes, I think it differs. Users active on meta have currently a more limited mission in mind than the company. And there is no requirement for users to just adopt the company's mission fully. In that regard it is appropriate. But users should be aware of the power balance. Ultimately the company decides upon the rules and what content is kept and what is not. If people keep that in mind, I see no big problems in everyone (not only users active on meta) following his/her own mission within the boundaries of the rules. The mission that is effectively accomplished on the main site is an average of all the individual missions.

If users realize that their own mission is too far away from the companies mission or the apparent mission of the other users, they should carefully evaluate if continued contribution is still worth it, including anticipating future developments and then adapt their contributions. For that purpose it would be helpful if the company's mission would be clearer.

Comment: It'll just start to clash if some users keep closing questions which others—perhaps even the company—want to keep open due to differing ideals.

Comment: @deceze If the company wants less questions to be closed, it could just say so. But it even lowered the threshold for close votes to three, so I guess for the moment they want more not less questions to be closed. Let's look at the close/reopen cycles. It's one thing that the company wanted to keep an eye on.

Comment: @deceze I thought a bit more about it and yes, if the individual missions differ by too much, you'll get internal friction and frustration. I added the last paragraph advocating to regularly rethink if further contribution is meaningful. I would rather retreat than continue a fight that is mostly fought by attrition.

Comment: Thanks for the observation about volunteer communities not necessarily sharing a single mission. We all participate for different reasons. The reasons don't even have to be very closely aligned, as long as our actions don't directly oppose the site's mission.

Answer (score 6):

## Meta's mission is to develop and provide guidance for internet janitorial staff.

### Develop

Write and debate assertions about policy and its effect on the site, potentially as it supports or detracts from the site's goals.

- "What do we do with self-promotion?"

### Provide

Come to consensus, or at least a truce, on how to execute policies (and I use this term loosely. Perhaps "behaviors" would be better) to use. If "Develop" is a legislative action, this is a judicial one.

- "Is doing *X* considered self-promotion?"

### Janitorial staff

Everyone who acts on content and—in so doing—influences what content looks like; from how it is initially written, to how ends up looking, and even whether it ultimately stays. This is the group who performs executive action on the non-Meta sites.

- "Aha! Here is some self-promotion. I will leave a polite comment suggesting conformance with the policy the site has agreed upon, because a polite comment is the policy for dealing with such."

Comment: I wouldn't call Jon Skeet "Janitorial staff".

Comment: @TravisJ I wouldn't call Jon Skeet an *"active member of Meta"*

Comment: Not sure if bundling legislative, persecutive and executive power in one place is a good idea actually. Meta might be too mighty (the often named meta effect).

Comment: @NickA - The scope of this answer expands beyond "active members of meta" when it gets into content creation. Also, as an aside, Jon was active on meta up until they all split. You can see his contributions on MSE.

Comment: @TravisJ This answer isn't about content creation. It _does_ have a bit about the pressure that moderation actions create on content creation. I use "moderation" here very loosely, because Meta informs the way some people vote, which in turn is designed to encourage better content creation.